# Implement Horizontal Scrollbar in Dropdown List

Tags: html, css, asp.net, scrollbar

I would like to add a horizontal scrollbar in a dropdownlist that exists within a Listview.
Currently some of the text from the database is very long and if I do not set a width the dropdownlist width is very long. I would like to set a fixed width but add a horizontal scrollbar to the dropdownlist. Is this possible?

Here is my dropdownlist:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">

                <asp:DropDownList ID="formtitle" runat="server" DataSourceID="FormTitleDataSource" DataTextField="FormTitle" DataValueField="FormTitle" style="width:auto;" AppendDataBoundItems="True" SelectedValue ='<%# Bind("FormTitle") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="">(none)</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

well here is a Horizontal scroll bar in a combo box or a listbox with up/down arrow key press functionality, i apologyze to provide only the url because it has images and those stuffs and it's a great tutorial...i hope it helps you...once more i apologyze to copy only the url http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12872/Horizontal-scroll-bar-in-a-combo-box-or-a-listbox